# Symfony Routing Question

Tags: php, pdf, routes, symfony1

I am running Symfony 1.4 on Linux. My application creates pdf files and saves the files in the following directory:
/srv/www/vhosts/myapp/htdocs/stmts

Here is an example of the path to a particular pdf file:
/srv/www/vhosts/myapp/htdocs/stmts/example_001.pdf

My symfony is installed in the following path:
/srv/www/vhosts/myapp/htdocs

How can I create a route from my Symfony application to the example_001.pdf file? I want to be able to create a link in my symfony application to the pdf file. When a user clicks on the link the pdf will be opened.

Thank You

Answer (score 4):

In order for using a route to make sense you would need to be doing something like this:

```
public function executeDownload(sfWebRequest $request)
{
    // assume this method holds the logic for generating or getting a path to the pdf
    $pdfPath = $this->getOrCreatePdf();

    // disbale the layout
    $this->setLayout(false);

    $response = $this->getResponse();

    // return the binary pdf dat directly int he response as if serving a static pdf file
    $response->setHttpHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="'. basename($pdfPath));
    $response->setContentType('application/pdf');
    $response->setContent(file_get_contents($pdfPath));

    return sfView::NONE;
}
```

That action would actually read the file and send the content. But unless you have a good reason for doing this its not advisable because youre going to incur unnecessary overhead from php.

If you do have a good reason for doin this (restricted access, dynamic file names, etc.) then you would simply determine what paramters you need to use in that action to determine the path to the pdf on the file system and set up a normal route. For example lets say your using a human recognizeable slug to refernece the file. Then you have a db record that holds a mapping of slug to file path. In that case the preceding action might look like this:

```
public function executeDownload(sfWebRequest $request)
{

   $q = Doctrine_Core::getTable('PdfAsset')
     ->createQuery('p')
     ->where('slug = ?', $request->getSlug());

    $this->forward404Unless($asset = $q->fetchOne());

    $pdfPath = $asset->getPath();

    // disbale the layout
    $this->setLayout(false);

    $response = $this->getResponse();

    // return the binary pdf dat directly in the response as if serving a static pdf file
    $response->setHttpHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="'. basename($pdfPath));
    $response->setContentType('application/pdf');
    $response->setContent(file_get_contents($pdfPath));

    return sfView::NONE;
}
```

With the corresponding route looking something like:

```
pdf_asset:
  url: /download/pdf/:slug
  params: {module: yourModule, action: 'download'}
```

Note if the files are large you might want to use `fopen` instead of `file_get_contents` and then read the data out as a stream so that you dont have to put it all in memory. This would require you to use a view though (but you would still set layout to false to prevent the layout from wrapping your streamed data).

Comment: I don't think I was clear enough in my initial question. The directory needs to have some type of security on it. Ideally I would like to use sfGuard to require authentication to read any of the pdf files in this directory. I would like to just use an href to the pdf files and put the links on a template. I don't want someone to obtain a url to one of the pdf files and then be able read the file with no authentication.

Comment: see my additional comments... you would jsut through an auth check in before you process the request like you would with any other secured action (or use security.yml to configure it). You dont necessarily have to use the DB i just used that to illustrate the point because its a typical example.